# Replace Reference DOCS file name from Sheet . file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Here is my example:

```
Sheet file with ID:
1uxEy8cPkNQVBVAFSHPBhvq0aRgRVZ0z2_I1AxK0gcuI
```

There are 2 columns:
Column A: contains the word to be replaced, for example:

> "A1": Le Minh Hai, "A2": ABC, "A3": HAIBA

Column B: contains the word you want to replace, for example:

> "B1": Nguyen Le Minh, "B2": CDE, "B3": BAAAA

There is a file named

> This is the file of Le Minh Hai

I want it to be changed to:

> This is Nguyen Le Minh's file

If there is a file with a different name

> This is the ABC file

It will change back to

> This is a CDE file

Same for other files

Code:

```
function getNewestFileInFolder() {
  var arryFileDates,file,fileDate,files,folder,folders,
      newestDate,newestFileID,objFilesByDate;

  folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('bvm-hd');  
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    folder = folders.next();
    files = folder.getFilesByType("application/vnd.google-apps.document");
    while (files.hasNext()){
      file = files.next();
  var newestFileID = file.getId();
  var currentDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newestFileID);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1t9T5FWedPLFcQ6wqcx4gGRHrrpldZHcLhgBJR0JbrPI');//ID sheet find and replace
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]);
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Trang tính1');
  var dongcuoi= sh.getLastRow();
  var dc = dongcuoi +1;
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(newSp.getId());
  var rgtxt = doc.getName();
  var rgrep = ss.getSheets()[0].getRange("A1:B"+dc);
  var repA = rgrep.getValues().filter(r => r.every(c => c.toString()));
  repA.forEach(e => rgtxt.replaceText(...e));      
  }
    }
  
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your question, unfortunately, I cannot understand `I want to replace keyword on DOCS Filename if it is present in the Sheet.` and `it doesn't work`. In order to correctly understand your issue and goal, can you provide the sample input and output situations as the image, and also can you provide the detail of the current issue?

Comment: @Tanaike: Thank you for your interest in my problem! I have posted the example below, please see for me

Comment: Thank you for replying. When you add more information, please add it to your question. In your current situation, the additional information is posted as an answer. Please delete it and include it in your question. And, from your additional information, in your goal, only the cells of "A1" and "B1" are used and you want to change the filename of Google Document to the value of "B1". Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I want to change the file name of the Google Docs to the value "B1", yes it is.
But I have a lot of words I need to change in columns "A" and "B"

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your goal from `But I have a lot of words I need to change in columns "A" and "B"`. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I have updated my question, hope you understand it better

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your updated question, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to rename the filename of Google Document in the specific folder using Spreadsheet.
- You want to change the existing filename including the values of column "A" to the values of column "B".
- For example, when the filename is `This is the file of Le Minh Hai`, you want to change it to `This is Nguyen Le Minh's file`.

In this case, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

```js
function getNewestFileInFolder() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1t9T5FWedPLFcQ6wqcx4gGRHrrpldZHcLhgBJR0JbrPI');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Trang tính1');
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('bvm-hd');
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    var files = folder.getFilesByType("application/vnd.google-apps.document");
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      file = files.next();
      var filename = file.getName();
      var check = values.filter(([a]) => filename.includes(a));
      if (check.length > 0) {
        file.setName(filename.replace(check[0][0], check[0][1]));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- From your script, I'm worried that there might be the folders of folder name of `bvm-hd`. So I use the while loop for retrieving the folders.
- The values can be retrieved from Spreadsheet by one call. So in this modified script, this script is moved to the out of loops.
- In order to change the filename, you can use `getName` and `setName` of Class File.

#### References:

- [getName() of Class File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getName())
- [setName() of Class File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setnamename)